# How to Identify my TFT LCD Driver Chip

Tags: stm32, tft, glcd, graphics

This is one of my  TFT LCD which I have no Technical details.

[image]

How can I find which driver chip they have used? I have previously  interfaced TFT based on RA8875 driver. So I Have a basic idea.
I have read about chip ID for the driver. But Ra8875 did int mention anything like that as far as I remember.
Can we read through 16 bit interface on some register and find?
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a google search on the flexcable code FKJ50002 and you will find several hits. One of the first is https://evertdekker.com/?p=257 which presents a library for that same display and claims that the controller is an SSD2119.

Comment: Thank you very Much Dear Bill. I think that solved the issue.